# Is there a way to dynamically type a function in a wrapped function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, metaprogramming

So say I have a simple use case - I want a function to be wrapped in another time tracking function. Rather than copy-paste my time tracking code everywhere I want to abstract the time tracking code by creating a wrapper function around my original function and creating a new function as a result. So I end up with a function like the following.

```
function wrapFunction(someFunction: Function) {
  const wrappedFunction = function() {
    let args = arguments;
    let beforeTime = new Date();
    someFunction.apply(args);
    let afterTime = new Date();
    console.log("Time Elapsed " + afterTime - beforeTime);
  };
  return {execute: wrappedFunction};
}
```

Then to use it I would do something like the following:

```
//Generate the wrapped function
let wrappedFunction = wrapFunction((param1 : string, param2: number) =>{
  console.log("Param1 = ", param1);
  console.log("Param2 = ", param2);
});
//This is the actual usage of the function
wrappedFunction.execute('param1', 2);
```

My question is: is there a way to dynamically set the function parameters of that returned .execute() in a way that Typescript can detect errors, and IDEs can pick up on the function parameters.

In the current state, I have no way to check what parameters I should be passing into .execute() without checking where the function was generated.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Unfortunately this doesn't allow my IDE to pickup the function parameters, but it does enforce the typing like I wanted! Not sure if the IDE thing is even possible - but this is close enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics and tuples in rest arguments:

```
function wrapFunction<A extends any[], R>(someFunction: (...a: A) => R) {
    const wrappedFunction = function (...args: A) {
        let beforeTime = new Date();
        let result = someFunction(...args);
        let afterTime = new Date();
        console.log("Time Elapsed " + (afterTime.getDate() - beforeTime.getDate()));
        return result;
    };
    return { execute: wrappedFunction };
}

//Generate the wrapped function
let wrappedFunction = wrapFunction((param1: string, param2: number) => {
    console.log("Param1 = ", param1);
    console.log("Param2 = ", param2);
});

wrappedFunction.execute('param1', 2); //ok now
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, use a generic function type:

```
function wrapFunction<F extends Function>(someFunction: F) {
  function wrappedFunction(...args) { // personal preference + performance boost
    const beforeTime = new Date();
    const result = someFunction.apply(this, args);
    const afterTime = new Date();
    console.log("Time Elapsed " + afterTime - beforeTime);
    return result;
  }

  return {execute: wrappedFunction as F }; // why this object though?
}
```

Comment: I would hesitate to use `F`  directly, this would imply any extra properties are preserved in `execute` which they are not. You can still use this solution but build a signature that will not include any extra properties of `F` using `ReturnType` and `Parameters`

Comment: @titian yes definetly, but I think that would be overkill here

Comment: Depends on usage I guess, but since typescript now allows us to assign things to functions directly and it ads those things directly to the function type it might end up causing confusion ..

Comment: Example:  https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAxc15gA82iApgB5SlgAmAzorpLAgHwAUdcAtqU-ggBcjAJSIA3gChEiUMwIoMmTKRr8WYdlAAWMOsPRgAngBpEAOkvpUAc32JDRgNoBdMeMQB6T4hWouYOgANr6opMCkYZCkiADUvpHAcKjchhAxAEZwcHRQ0jKIEAi5iBnhyaQAKjC8iAC8iGCkyIgAIuhU7CIA3PkyRWAlYXQgQVD1iFy86gTmWJhBRlq6dGbWdj19hcXj6MBUqNW1DU0t7Z2bBYhhUCCoSMOjUL0yAL6S+Td3SOIUpBAgKjCNDzVQzBAOBiOSGMRCvbpeHzIbRGRA6PSIOAZABW-3GOjgIBs2gA-JJ3pI5AIkFRcl0JB93rSoHMJgBGXognB4DRaUi5ETmP4Aqis7xohh0dBGBgwKAAcgYcAA1qVAY04OMwsFFmjtJFSEA